# Validate between the range of first and last element in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to validate the range of the next and previous element in JavaScript. Where when I click on the next button the value must stop at the end of the array (third) and when I click on the previous button the value should stop at the first element.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    
var text = [
    "first item",
    "second item",
    "third item"
];

var Current = 0;

document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text;

function Prev() {
    if (Current == 0) {
        Current = text.length - 1;
    } else {
        Current--;
    }

    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
}

function Next() {
    if (Current == text.length - 1) {
        Current = 0
    } else {
        Current++;
    }

    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
}
    
</script>
    
<div id="textHere"></div>
    
<div>
    <button onclick="Next();">Next!</button>
    <button onclick="Prev();">Previous</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace code inside `if` condition in both `Next()` and `Prev()` with `return`?

Comment: What is the problem with the code that you've shown?

Comment: If you want it to "stop", don't set `Current` to the wrapped index (i.e., don't set it to `text.length - 1` or `0`) when it hits the outer bounds. Just do nothing, or disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **not** loop around, don't change the value of `Current` when at a bound of your list in your `Prev()` and `Next()` functions.

That would be:

```js
function Prev() {
  if (Current == 0) {
    // we're at the begining of the array, don't do anything
    return;
  } else {
    Current--;
  }

  document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
}

function Next() {
  if (Current == text.length - 1) {
    // we're at the end of the array, don't do anything
    return;
  } else {
    Current++;
  }

  document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

Below has the solution, which includes the proper conditions `>` and `<` (instead of `==`).

I've also simplified the code to make it more readable.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = [
      "first item",
      "second item",
      "third item"
    ];
  
    var Current = 0;
  
    document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
  
    function Prev() {
      if (Current > 0) { 
        Current--;        // Only subtract 1 from Current if it was greater than 0
      }
      document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }
  
    function Next() {
      if (Current < text.length - 1) {
        Current++;        // Only add 1 to Current if it was less than the last index
      }
      document.getElementById("textHere").innerHTML = text[Current];
    }
  </script>
  
  <div id="textHere"></div>
  
  <div>
    <button onclick="Next();">Next!</button>
    <button onclick="Prev();">Previous</button>
  </div>
</body>
```